# How to classify a video into a category based on the data on a .csv?

Tags: python, node.js, reactjs, docker

Got a .CSV (both with header and without) from a python script using youtube api v3, I have an .CSV from other videos as well, I would like to know ways to classify them into categories based on the content of their respective .csv, like for example:

#of likes >5 --> popular

#of likes <5 --> not popular

And later show them on a browser classified into those categories. The idea is to sorta automatize the whole process since I need it to work with whatever video I feed into the script.

Don't have a code to share since I don't know where to begin with.

Sample data:

[image: sample data]
Cheers.

Comment: We can't possibly help you without seeing a sample of the data you're working with.  If there is a column for "likes" and "dislikes", then the code should be obvious.

Comment: Not like and dislike only  # of likes, hence my issue. Gonna update the post with sample data.